# Play movie using QTMovieView crashes with Autolayout

Tags: objective-c, xcode, osx-lion, quicktime

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
self.objMovie = [QTMovie movieWithURL:url error:&error];
if(self.objMovie != nil)
{
    // Mark the movie as not editable
    [self.objMovie setAttribute:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:QTMovieEditableAttribute];
    [self.objPlayer setMovie:self.objMovie];
    //[[self.objPlayer window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    NSLog(@"Error in Video = %@",error);
    [self.objPlayer play:self];
}
```

Code above works fine for manual layout, but crash when i am trying to use same with Autolayout.

Env: OSx version: 10.8.3

Getting Error:

-[StdMovieUISliderCell sliderType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107157990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [has anyone seen "[StdMovieUISliderCell sliderType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942006/has-anyone-seen-stdmovieuislidercell-slidertype-unrecognized-selector-sent-t)
File a bug report at http://bugreporter.apple.com -- it'll likely be closed as a duplicate, but every vote counts.